# Best approach to get filename from picked file/image

Tags: android, image, uri, filepath

Most of the code snippets I've seen here and there about prompting user to pick a file or image, have the **onActivityResult method** use a function like the one below to get the chosen file path.

My question is why go through all that, when Uri has the ready to use function **Uri.getPath()** ? Are there advantages or dissadvantages in the one approach or the other?

onActivityResult code

```
   Uri source = data.getData();
   String fileName=getRealPathFromURI(this, source);
```

get path function

```
   public static String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
          Cursor cursor = null;
          try { 
            String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri,  proj, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
          } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
              cursor.close();
            }
          }
    }
```

I actually had my app crashing using the getRealPathMethod when I picked a file/image from dropbox...while using the Uri.getPath() method i had no problem whatsoever. So..what's the deal here? Am I missing something?

Comment: You don't have to have a filename to get the content. And you are not supposed to have one. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html#open see open inputstream / bitmap example (that part is not exclusive to android 4.4)

Comment: ok...but that has nothing to do with the question. Maybe what i'm trying to do requires getting the filename not the content.

Comment: There is maybe not even a file. Or one that you can't access. You can't use a path in all cases. (and that is essentially the answer to "what's the deal here? Am I missing something?")

Answer (score 0):

Try like this way

```
final String [] consDirNames  = new String[constDir.length];
        // directory names 
        for(int i=0;i<constDir.length;i++){

            consDirNames[i]=constDir[i].getName();
                    File booths[]=        constDir[i].listFiles(new FileFilter() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean accept(File pathname) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            return pathname.getName().endsWith(".pdf");
                        }
                });    ;
        consDirMap.put(consDirNames[i], booths);
        fileMap.put(consDirNames[i],constDir[i].getAbsolutePath() );
    }
```